# Is there any good way to use SVN for uploads directory?

Tags: uploads, svn, version-control

We just got our servers set up with SVN which works great. Wordpress upgrades and plugin installations are managed manually, which all goes through SVN as well, but I can't work out a good way to version control upload directories.

The best solution I can think of is to periodically go into the folders, look through the images to make sure they are legitimate (no self-unpacking shell scripts, etc) and commit them... either that or svn:ignore the entire folder.

Is there a better way to do this? All the discussion I can find on Google has to do with using SVN for Wordpress installs, not dynamically managed assets.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the action `add_attachment` and perform an SVN commit.

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'svn_commit_attachments' );

function svn_commit_attachments( $attachment_ID )
{
    // collect data about the attachment, for example its path, the user and so on.
     shell_exec ( '$ svn commit -m "$user added file $filename."' )
}
```

Comment: This is certainly an option... I wonder how difficult it would be to write a plugin so users could do a "verification" commit. Part of the reason we moved to SVN was to catch malicious changes made on our servers, so having uploads automatically committed scares me a bit. I'm gonna play with this snippet and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @kristinachilds This is just a rough draft. If you had used Git you could add those uploads to the _stage_. But as far as I’m aware there is no such concept in SVN.

Comment: This whole version control concept is new to me. Coudda Shoudda Wouldda... of course I would learn that a week after our new infrastructure was built :)